# How to make tab with boostrap, which has its tab show products of a category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I did see a page somewhere on internet, which made impressive tabs like below:

```
All|Fashion|Jewerry|Food
```

When user clicks on `All` then it will show all items.
when user clicks om `Fashion` or else then i will show only items of its category.
I remember that each item have something like `All Fashion`/`All Food` so that the tab control panel would show/hide item.

I tried to find some tutorial about tab on bootstrap. But i did not see any example like that in document.

Could someone please show how to do that with bootstrap and without bootstrap???
The reasons's is i am only good with back-end.
I am learning front-end.

### Thanks in advance.

i did
it without bootstrap
html:

```
    <ul id='list_tabs'>
        <li><a data-filter='*' href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a data-filter='meat' href='#'>meat</a></li>
        <li><a data-filter='fish' href='#'>fish</a></li>            
    </ul>
    <ul id='list_products'>
        <li data-category='fish meat'>product 1 </li>
        <li data-category='fish'>product 2 </li>
        <li data-category='meat'>product 3 </li>        
    </ul>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#list_tabs').click(function(event){
       var filter = $(event.target).attr('data-filter');        

        $('#list_products li').each(function(){
           var item = $(this);  
           if(filter=='*'||(item.attr('data-category').indexOf(filter)!= -1))
             item.show();
           else 
             item.hide();
       });
    });
});
```

I'm still looking into how to do it with bootstrap.
Thank everyone for helping.

---

P/s: I did saw same control like that in [this site](http://wp.pistaciatheme.com/pistacia/)
I am looking into it. But i still hope someone could help me.

Comment: Some tab stuff with bootstrap [Bootstrap tabs](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panels-with-nav-tabs)

Comment: sorry but if that's really easily like that then i don't have to go and ask in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I loved checking [this](http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content) too. You can improvise as you learn. I give you a setup for you to start here.

```js
// optional code: Throw event on tab change and work with it.
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  var elem = $(e.target),
    target = elem.attr("href");
  if (target === hashify('Tab_1') || target === hashify('Tab_3') || target === hashify('Tab_5')) {
    $(hashify('testImage')).attr('src', 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a');
  }
  else {
    $(hashify('testImage')).attr('src', 'https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png');
  }
});
  
function hashify(str){
  return '#' + str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#Tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#Tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#Tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#Tab_4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#Tab_5" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active in" id="Tab_1">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab_2">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab_3">
    Tab 3
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab_4">
    Tab 4
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab_5">
    Tab 5
  </div>
  <img id = "testImage" src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="Logo" height="150" width="150">
</div>
<
```

Comment: i am confused. About javascript `a[data-toggle="tab"` i don't know where to put it?? after bootstrap.js??? And something else. But maybe i must find out myself. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hey you can just ignore that part. You still have a HTML page with tabs...
@Mirai Do yo need to work with events while changing the tabs?

Comment: Yes you need to include bootstrap.js in your HTML file to use this.

Comment: yes i do. A item can be child of many tabs or a tab. And i want to it show up when  its tabs  is clicked.

Comment: I have updated the code . Please check. The same image element changes it 'src' if you click different tabs. Is this useful? @Mirai

Comment: Thank for helping me. But what i am looking for is not like that.  I am very impressive  your skill. I hope my skill will same as yours in someday.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @Mirai . Its an exaggeration :p. It would be you good if you can accept and/or upvote the answer if it was useful for your problem mentioned in this question. So that others having similar problem can find it useful in later times. :D

Comment: Actually, i  don't want to say it straight. But i am really appreciate foryour helping. But my professor taught me that  " i hate half-heart student'